# Assessing the ability of two quantitative methods measuring the same thing

Tags: reliability, agreement-statistics, measurement, intraclass-correlation

Suppose I have two scientific approaches to measuring the same physical quantity taking values between $[0,1]$. One (say method A) is generally accepted to be more accurate under certain conditions, but it is more of a gross measure (low spatial resolution). The other method is newer in the field, has the a higher resolution, but may have some accuracy problems at lower levels.

What is the best way to determine how well the two methods agree? I've visualized it with a scatter plot, and fit the data to a straight line and can get a slope close to 1.0, reasonably small intercept, and $R^2$ quite near 1.0 -- but isn't that more of a correlation measure?

I would appreciate any suggestions on what types of statistical methods to explore.

Comment: Do you want to model your degree of belief in the "generally accepted to be more accurate" and "may have some accuracy problems" statements?  If so you may want to look at Bayesean techniques.  When I've seen other people do this kind of calibration activity (I recall a paper with different models of radiosondes) the relations have been non-linear, so you may want to look at a non-linear model.